# Unity Ray-cast not specific enough

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The ray cast appears to only update when I move and is randomly positioned, any help would be much appreciated.

```
    `    void Update(){
    if(IsBruiserFollowingMarkerRay){
        RaycastHit hit;
        BruiserMoveToVisuals.SetActive(true);
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, Range)){
       // Debug.Log(hit.transform.position);
        BruiserMoveToDefault.transform.position = hit.transform.position;
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a ray-cast does not work as expected, use the Debug.DrawRay() to visually see what is happening. Something like this:

```
    if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, Range))
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward * Range, Color.yellow, 1f);
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward * Range, Color.green, 1f);
    }
```

Note that we need to multiply the direction with the Range to visually show the ray with the same length as the Raycast(). You should now be able to see why the ray-cast is not giving the answers you expect. If you can't see any ray (neither yellow or green), it is probably that the Range is 0 or the fpsCam is not positioned where you expect it to be.